# What does the "show_quantity" config setting do?

Tags: commerce

The product entity_view_display config has a 3rd party "show_quantity" setting, but it's seemingly not used anywhere.
What does it do?

Comment: Do a search on the modules folder for that string, and see if/which module is adding it.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did. `commerce_product` it's defines this in `commerce_product.schema.yml`, but it's not used anywehere. I opened an issue thread on d.o, which was summarily closed.